motion.span no funcion al agregar la animación, Framer Motion
estoy utilizando Framer Motion con react, el componente que quiero animar es un span, pero al intentar hacerlo no realiza ninguna acción.
Ahora el codigo de mi componente es:
<motion.span
    key={`category-${index}`}
    className="bg-primary text-xs p-2 rounded-md"
    initial={{scale: 0}}
    animate={{scale: 1}}
    exit={{scale: 0}}
    transition={{
        duration: 0.5,
        ease: "easeOut",
    }}
>
    {item.name}
</motion.span>

Cuando hago el cambio de index, no realiza la acción, ahora cuando cambio un div en lugar del span y funciona correctamente, por lo que hay algo que no esté realizando o que tendria que agregar algo para que se realizara la animación?

El <motion.span> es un elemento de alguna lista? porque eso parece, si es una lista se debe configurar el ul y el li con framer también

Si, pero no, si hay un index y objeto item, pero no esta dentro de un listado o map, son dos variables const, indext si es un useState y item es un useMemo, asi los manejo

De mi lado funciona usando state para index y useMemo para la estructura item, puedo ver el zoom out de la propiedad name, si pudieras agregar como tienes el set up de tu lado,
